# Postgres 2d array dynamic length

Tags: postgresql

postgres supports multi dimensional arrays, however the length is restricted.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    field1 text[][]
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{{null, null}, {foo, null}, {foo, bar}}');
```

this works fine, but if I do

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{{}, {foo}, {foo, bar}}');
```

this gives an error 'malformed array literal: "{{}, {foo}, {foo, bar}}"'. Can I do something like the above but without errors?

Comment: I have a hard time finding justification for de-normalizing using single dimension arrays.  The use case for de-normalizing a model using a 2d array seem even smaller.

Comment: We can break it down to another table but the overall structure of the database is complicated enough so a 2d array will be easier for our implementation and maintenance

Comment: e.g. a 2d array representing Intersection/union of groups of elements [[a], [b, c]] -> a ∩ (b ∩ c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a domain:

```
CREATE DOMAIN x AS text[];

CREATE TABLE test (field1 x[]);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (ARRAY[
                            ARRAY[]::x,
                            ARRAY['foo']::x,
                            ARRAY['foo', 'bar']::x
                         ]);

TABLE test;

           field1           
════════════════════════════
 {"{}","{foo}","{foo,bar}"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is there a way to insert by literal constant? Because I'm using Hasura and it only works with array literal

Comment: Sure, use the exact format of the final query result.