# Aggregate array of array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with array values.

```
create table A (v int[]);

insert into A (v) values ('{1,2,3}');
insert into A (v) values ('{}');
insert into A (v) values (NULL);
insert into A (v) values ('{4,5}');
```

And table for aggregating this values

```
create table B (v int[][]);
```

I need insert all rows from a to b so `b.v` should be

```
{{123},{},{},{4,5}}
```

How you see, also I need map null to empty array. I tired something like

```
insert into B (v) 
select array_agg(v) from A
```

But it's not worked - Can't aggreate empty or null values.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation:

> Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension. A mismatch causes an error, for example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO sal_emp
>     VALUES ('Bill',
>     '{10000, 10000, 10000, 10000}',
>     '{{"meeting", "lunch"}, {"meeting"}}');
> ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
> ```

As a solution based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932195/postgres-2d-array-dynamic-length) you may

1. Use custom domain of array type:

   ```
   create domain int_array int[]
   ```
2. Use it in your target table:

   ```
   create table b(val int_array[])
   ```
3. Create custom aggregate for this type:

   ```
   create aggregate array_array_agg(int_array) (
     sfunc = array_append,
     stype = int_array[],
     initcond = '{}'
   )
   ```
4. And use this custom aggregate:

   ```
   insert into b(val)
   select array_array_agg(v)
   from a

   INSERT 0 1
   ```

```
select *
from b
```

| val |
| --- |
| {"{1,2,3}","{}",NULL,"{4,5}"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_3lAi1Cs)